# How to programatically evaluate expression(spel/variable reference) used in annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Say that I have use case for finding method annotated via say `@Scheduled(cron = "${variable}")`, and I'd like to know the value of "cron" parameter. If I check via reflection, no surprise, I will find there value `"${variable}"`.

Can someone share link/snipet how to evaluate variables/spel expression present in annotation? I found some answers, but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to extend @crizzis answer, maybe filling the missing part.

Fist you need to inject/autowire `ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;`. Looking at implementation of `ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver` and it's parent `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver` it seems to me, that full code which does variable substitution and spell needs one more line:

```
BeanExpressionResolver beanExpressionResolver = beanFactory.getBeanExpressionResolver();    
String expressionWithSubstitutedVariables = beanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(expression);
Object resultWithResolvedSPEL = beanExpressionResolver.evaluate(expressionWithSubstitutedVariables, new BeanExpressionContext(beanFactory, null));
```

then string like `#{!${some-boolean-variable} ? 'a' : 'b'}` was correctly evaluated for me. Not sure if this is the way-to-go as I don't know spring well, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are a couple of ways, but the easiest is probably:

```
beanFactory.getBeanExpressionResolver().evaluate(
    "${variable}", 
    new BeanExpressionContext(beanFactory, null))
```

Comment: Thanks, but fo some reason this does not work for me. SPEL like `#{3*3}` is evaluated, but existing variable reference like `${variable}` is not, and just the same string is returned.

Comment: looking at the code I can force it to look for `${` instead of `#{`, but this does not seem to support evaluating variables, just spel. Is there something which can do both, just like say `@Value` annotation? Or can you present complete sample, as this one seems not to work as intended.